# Change to iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

On gmx.net I want to click on a hyperlink in an email.

But the hyperlink is enclosed with two iframes.

How do I change into it?

My approach:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@class="app-stack_children--active"]')))

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@class="js-box-flex need-overlay"]')))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your approach is correct. This is possibly due to an incorrect XPath. Sometimes, you target the incorrect iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, your XPath is incorrect.

You have to either use

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@class='app-stack__children l-vertical app-stack__children--active']')))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//iframe[contains(@class, 'app-stack_children--active']')))
```

Obviously, the first option is better than the second one. There's always a chance that `contains()` will match more than one element. It is less probable if using equality.